# remove non matching elements from matrix

Tags: matrix, octave, rows

I am trying to compare two matrices `A` and `B`. If elements in the first two columns of `A` match those in `B`, I want to delete all non matching rows from `A`. The third column in `B` should not factor into the comparison.

```
A = [1 2 3      B = [1 2 8
     3 4 5           3 4 5]
     6 7 8]
```

Desired result:

```
A = [1 2 3
     3 4 5]
```

So far I only found ways to remove duplicate entries, which is the exact opposite of what I want. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A = [1 2 3;3 4 5;7 8 9];
B = [1 2 8; 3 4 5];
tmp = min([size(A,1) size(B,1)]); % get size to loop over
k = false(tmp,1); % storage counter
for ii = 1:tmp 
    if all(A(ii,1:2)==B(ii,1:2)) % if the first two columns match
        k(ii)=true; % store
    end
end

C = A(k,:) % extract requested rows
```

Answer (score 2):

You can efficiently use [`ismember`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/ismember.html) for this task:

```
% Input matrices
A = [1 2 3; 3 4 5; 7 8 9];
B = [1 2 8; 3 4 5];

A1 = A(:,1:2);                   % Extract first two columns for both matrices
B1 = B(:,1:2);
[~,ii] = ismember(A1,B1,'rows'); % Returns which rows in A1 are also in B1
ii = ii(ii>0);                   % Where ii is zero, it's a non-matching row
A(ii,:)                          % Index to keep only matching rows
```

All of this can be written more compactly, but I wanted to show the step-by-step process first:

```
[~,ii] = ismember(A(:,1:2),B(:,1:2),'rows');
A(ii(ii>0),:)
```